# Ошибка: попытка деления на ноль

Tags: c#, asp.net, математика

Я пытаюсь присвоить переменной типа double математическое выражение, которое в свою очередь тоже состоит из переменных

```
 countPercent = 100 / (count_pipe_plan / (count_pipe_fact1 + count_pipe_fact));
```

что получает дебагер:

```
count_pipe_plan = 162
```

`count_pipe_fact1 = 1`

```
count_pipe_fact = 194
```

Дебаггер выбрасывает мне ошибку, что я пытаюсь поделить на ноль. В чем может быть дело?

Comment: Типы у переменных целочисленные? Попробуйте `countPercent = 100 / (count_pipe_plan / (count_pipe_fact1 + count_pipe_fact * 1.0));`

Comment: Да, у переменных integer тип

Comment: вы же в курсе, что если считать цулые числа, то `1 / 194` будет равно `0`, так как целые числа не имеют дробной части?

Comment: Теперь в курсе, спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Типичная ошибка приведения типов. Вы оперируете целыми числами и почему то ожидаете, что они будут содержать дробную часть.

У вас есть 2 варианта. Либо добавить дробный операнд вот так

```
countPercent = 100 / (count_pipe_plan 
               / (count_pipe_fact1 + count_pipe_fact * 1.0));
```

Либо явно приводить типы вот так

```
countPercent = 100 / ((double)count_pipe_plan 
               / ((double)count_pipe_fact1 + (double)count_pipe_fact));
```

Но вообще ваше выражение можно переписать вот так

```
 countPercent = 100 * ((double)count_pipe_fact1 + (double)count_pipe_fact) 
               / (double)count_pipe_plan;
```

Хотя вы, наверное, всё таки имели ввиду это

```
 countPercent = 100 * (double)count_pipe_plan 
               / ((double)count_pipe_fact1 + (double)count_pipe_fact);
```