# Программа не считает проценты

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int s = Convert.ToInt32(T1.Text);
        int c = Convert.ToInt32(T2.Text);
        int r = rnd.Next(1, c);
        L1.Content = "Стрелки" + "\n";
        for (int i = 1; i <= s; i++)
        {
            L1.Content += "" + i + "\n";
        }
        L2.Content = "Выстрелы" + "\n";
        for (int i = 1; i <= s; i++)
        {
            L2.Content += "" + c + "\n";
        }
        L3.Content = "Попадания" + "\n";
        for (int i = 1; i <= s; i++)
        {
            int r1 = rnd.Next(1, c+1);
            L3.Content += "" + r1 + "\n";
            L4.Content = "Проценты" + "\n";
            for (int d = 1; d <= s; d++)
            {
                L4.Content += "" + r1 / c * 100 + "\n";
            }
        }
```

В чём может быть ошибка подсчёта?[image: Скрин программы]

Comment: Если что, где выстрелы значение будет 10

Comment: Картинку нельзя скопировать и ставить в Visual Studio, а перепечатывать ваш код, чтобы только его проверить нието не будет. Приведите код текстом.

Comment: на первый взгляд, обычная [ошибка округления](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1029968/179763)

Comment: Я заметил ошибка не только в этом, но и в учёте программой только самое последнее значение из попаданий

Comment: ну это уже вам лучше знать. Как я уже писал, нет кода текстом - считай нет вопроса.

Comment: я же уже добавил выше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы улучшили свой вопрос, добавив код. Я не поленился и его поправил. 
Обратите внимание, как вы заполняли L4, вы на каждой итерации создавали текст для него заново, вместо того, чтобы просто добавлять 1 запись.

```
private void Button_Click(object sender)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int s = 10; //Convert.ToInt32(T1.Text);
    int c = 15; // Convert.ToInt32(T2.Text);
    int r = rnd.Next(1, c);
    L1.Content = "Стрелки" + "\n";
    for (int i = 1; i <= s; i++)
    {
        L1.Content += "" + i + "\n";
    }
    L2.Content = "Выстрелы" + "\n";
    for (int i = 1; i <= s; i++)
    {
        L2.Content += "" + c + "\n";
    }
    L3.Content = "Попадания" + "\n";
    L4.Content = "Проценты" + "\n";
    for (int i = 1; i <= s; i++)
    {
        int r1 = rnd.Next(1, c + 1);
        L3.Content += "" + r1 + "\n";           
        L4.Content += "" + 1.0*r1 / c * 100 + "\n";     
        //если в процентах вам интересны только целые числа, то             
        // L4.Content += "" + 100 *r1 / c + "\n";   
    }
}
```